# Delete an element on a Linked List

Tags: c, algorithm, linked-list

I wanted to delete all nodes of a Linked List that contain some value, but the algorithm that I have implemented doesn't work as I hoped!
when I execute the program it shows that all the nodes have been deleted!

output :

```
The List is empty
```

can someone help me to detect the problem ?

```
typedef struct node
{
    int data;
    struct list* next;
}node;

typedef struct list
{
    node* start,*end;
}list;

void delete(list** ptr,int element)
{
    if((*ptr)->start==NULL)    return;

    node* previous=NULL;
    list* new_ptr=(list*)malloc(sizeof(list));

    new_ptr->start=(*ptr)->start;
    new_ptr->end=(*ptr)->end;

    while(new_ptr->start)
    {
        if(new_ptr->start->data==element)
        {
            if(previous==NULL)
            {
                node* temp=new_ptr->start;
                new_ptr->start=new_ptr->start->next;
                (*ptr)->start=new_ptr->start;
                free(temp);
            }
            else
            {
                node* temp=new_ptr->start;
                new_ptr->start=new_ptr->start->next;
                previous->next=new_ptr->start;
                free(temp);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            previous=new_ptr->start;
            new_ptr->start=new_ptr->start->next;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: OT: Your "stack" is not a stack but a linked list. And most of your names in your code are misleading. Proper naming is important. Naming a function that deletes certain elements of a list `pop` is not a good idea.  `struct list` is a list element, not a list.

Comment: Your code is leaking memory, you allocate new memory for a `list` referenced by `new_ptr` that you never free.